# default selected in multiselect dropdown in yii

Tags: yii

it will not display default selected value in my multi select dropdown list and i am not getting the mistak.  is dropdown list accept array for defalt select array list

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    .......
        $cust= implode('_',$_POST['supplier'] ['manufacture']);
        $model->customer = $cust;
        $model->save();
    ........
}
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->customer  = explode('_',$model->customer);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
      $cust= implode(',',$_POST['supplier']['manufacturer']);
        $model->customer = $cust`enter code here`;
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### View

```
<?= 
$form->field($model, 'car_manufacturer[]')->dropDownList($model->getcustinfo(), [
    'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',
    ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only attribute name.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'car_manufacturer')->dropDownList($model->getcustinfo(), [
          'multiple'=>'multiple',
          'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',  ])?>
```

Comment: it is an multi select dropdown means i want value's of multiple select options. if i use only attribute name it gives me only one value

Comment: Are you sure about that? In my case it returns array of selected values.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `selected value` in options:

```
['options' => $yourvalue => ['Selected'=>'selected']]
```

You should pass an `array` in options:

```
 ['options' =>
                    [                        
                      $id1 => ['selected' => true]
                    ],
                     [                        
                      $id2 => ['selected' => true]
                    ],

          ]
```

You can use `foreach` loop to make this `array`.

Comment: but $yourvalue is an array variable and this method not allow array

Comment: Hey i did the same but in Yii1 not in Yii2 so i just tell you for this you have to create a array to pass in options please check my updated answer :)